# Handling 404 and other bad responses with looping twitteR queries

Tags: r, twitter

I would like it if my loop wouldn't break if I get an error.  I want it to just move on to the next iteration.  This example is a minimal example of the error I'm getting and the loop breaking.  In my real application I'm iterating through some of the followers I've generated from another script.

```
library(twitteR)
#set oauth...
for(i in 1:10) {
+ x <- getUser("nalegezx") }
```

> Error in twInterfaceObj$doAPICall(paste("users", "show", sep = "/"), params = params,  : 
>         client error: (404) Not Found

I understand that this loop would simply rewrite the same response to x. I'm just interested in not breaking the loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not an expert in the R Twitter API, but I can suggest that you consider placing your call to `getUser()` inside a `try` block like this:

```
for (i in 1:10) {
    x <- try(getUser("sdlfkja"))
}
```

This should stop your code from crashing in the middle of the loop.  If you want to also have separate logic when a warning or error occurs in the loop, you can use `tryCatch`:

```
for (i in 1:10) {
    x <- tryCatch(getUser("sdlfkja"),
                  warning = function(w) {
                                print("warning"); 
                                # handle warning here
                            },
                  error = function(e) {
                              print("error");
                              # handle error here
                          })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I accepted Tim's answer because it resolved the problem I had but for the specific instance of getting many results from twitter on the profile for users I used `lookupUsers` which does the job for me without messing with my request limit.