# Not Found (HTTP 404) twitteR loop error

Tags: r, twitter

I am aiming to build a twitter network by constructing an igraph from twitter relationships.

After 10 iterations R gives me this error

Error in twInterfaceObj$doAPICall(paste("users", "show", sep = "/"), params = params,  : 
Not Found (HTTP 404).

```
# Grab latest tweets

tweets_galway <- searchTwitter('#galway', n=100)

# make into df
df <- do.call("rbind", lapply(tweets_galway, as.data.frame))

# extract users from galway hashtag tweets

galway_users = df$screenName

connectiondf=data.frame()

for( i in 1:100)
{
  name<-getUser(galway_users[i])
  following<-name$getFriends()
  following <- twListToDF(following)
  connect1=cbind(follower=galway_users[i],following=following$screenName)
  follower<-name$getFollowers()
  follower <- twListToDF(follower)
  connect2=cbind(follower=follower$screenName,following=galway_users[i])

  connection<-rbind(connect1,connect2)
  connectiondf=rbind(connectiondf,connection)
  print(i)
}
```

Why am I getting this error? Apologies if this is a silly query but I am new to R

Comment: Similar to question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30691415/handling-404-and-other-bad-responses-with-looping-twitter-queries) which has an accepted response.